# Winforms - what is the simplest way to update a property in thread safe manner

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

I have the following code that I have been using to Set properties in a thread safe manner (adapted from [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150994/whats-the-best-way-for-a-net-winforms-application-to-update-itself-without-usi), but I cannot adapt it to get the property.

This is my set property in thread safe way code.

```
public static void SetPropertyThreadSafe(this TControl self, Action setter)
    where TControl : Control
{
    if (self.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var invoker = (Action)(() => setter(self));
        self.Invoke(invoker);
    }
    else
    {
        setter(self);
    }
}
```

Which is called by doing the following:

```
this.lblNameField.SetPropertyThreadSafe(p => p.Text = "Name:");
```

This is my attempt at a get property in thread safe way code.

```
public static TResult GetPropertyThreadSafe(this TControl self, Func getter)
    where TControl : Control
{
    if (self.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var invoker = (Func)((TControl control) => getter(self));
        return (TResult)self.Invoke(invoker);
    }
    else
    {
        return getter(self);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. I'd hopefully like to call it by doing the following:

```
string name = this.lblNameField.GetPropertyThreadSafe(p => p.Text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
public static TResult GetPropertyThreadSafe<TControl, TResult>(this TControl self, Func<TControl, TResult> getter)
    where TControl: Control
{
    if (self.InvokeRequired)
    {
        return (TResult)self.Invoke(getter, self);
    }
    else
    {
        return getter(self);
    }
}
```

You call it by the following:

```
bool visible = this.lblNameField.GetPropertyThreadSafe(p => p.Visible)
```