# C# SetPropertyThreadSafe vs Invoke thread-safe calls

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, invoke

Which of these two methods are better to update the UI from another thread? 
(for me they work both, but which is safer?)
I would prefer the SetPropertyThreadSafe method as it needs less code.

1.

```
label1.SetPropertyThreadSafe(() => this.label1.Text, "New Value");
```

2.

```
if (label1.InvokeRequired)
{
   label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
   label1.Text="New Value"; }));
}
```

Comment: define *better* ... otherwise it is just opinion based ...

Comment: Isn't that just an extension method for calling the invoke? They have an identical level of 'safeness'

Comment: They do exactly the same, so you should use 1st, cause it's more prettier. We want our code pretty, don't we? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SetPropertyThreadSafe` is not a method built in to .NET, if you are using [this implmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298568/winforms-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-update-a-property-in-thread-safe-manner)

```
public static TResult GetPropertyThreadSafe<TControl, TResult>(this TControl self, Func<TControl, TResult> getter)
    where TControl: Control
{
    if (self.InvokeRequired)
    {
        return (TResult)self.Invoke(getter, self);
    }
    else
    {
        return getter(self);
    }
}
```

Then the two examples you posted are doing the exact same thing so there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you head

1.

```
label1.SetPropertyThreadSafe(() => this.label1.Text, "New Value");
label2.SetPropertyThreadSafe(() => this.label1.Text, "New Value2");
```

and 2.

```
if (label1.InvokeRequired)
{
   label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
   {
   label1.Text="New Value"; 
   label2.Text="New Value2"; 
   }));
}
```

Then (2) is clearly better as it has a much lower overhead.   But in your case there is nothing to choose between them.

If you know you are on another thread, there is no need for the "if InvokeRequired".

Comment: you cannot update label2 with invoke test only for label1

Comment: @MarioM, you can if you know they are both running in the same top level window, as both WPF and WinForms ONLY supports one message queue per top level window, therefore there can ONLY be 1 UI thread per top level window.

Comment: It is VERY hard to get more then one message queue in a process even when you try to!